# Rename tgz to tar.gz while using sbt-native-packager

Tags: sbt, sbt-native-packager

I use the `sbt-native-packager` to build a gzipped tar file which has the extension `.tgz`. I then add that artifact using

```
artifact in (Compile, (packageZipTarball in Universal)) := {
  val previous: Artifact = (artifact in (Compile, (packageZipTarball in Universal))).value
  previous.withClassifier(Some("assembly")).withExtension("tar.gz")
 },
 addArtifact(artifact in (Compile, (packageZipTarball in Universal)), (packageZipTarball in Universal))
```

With this config the `.tgz` file gets published as `.tar.gz` to Nexus or the local repo.

How can I rename the `.tgz` in the target directory to `.tar.gz` without affecting the artifact publishing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make sure I got your question right:

```
$ sbt universal:packageZipTarball
```

produces a file with the extension `.tgz`. What you want is a file with the extension `.tar.gz`.

You can achieve this by overrding the `universal:packageZipTarball` and simply move the result. I haven't tested this code, but it should give you a rough idea

```
packageZipTarball in Universal := {
   val targzFile = universal:packageZipTarball
   val renamedFile = targzFile.getParent / targzFile.getName.replaceAll("\\.tgz$", ".tar.gz")
   IO.move(targzFile, renamedFile)
   renamedFile
}
```

Cheers,
Muki